# Accidentally removed terminal prompt

Tags: command-line, prompt

I tried to remove my old version of python on my Linux laptop with the terminal but accidentally removed the terminal app.

How to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for "Terminal". Then click install.

[image: _Ubuntu Software Center_]